# Custom Pathing on Excel Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems with the right keywords to research for this further. For now I'm having trouble customizing the path for an excel function. Here is my sample code to give you better visualization:

```
=VLOOKUP([path]\Attendance & now() & !G1:I13,[paht]\Attendance & now()-1 & !G:1,1,FALSE)
```

In here you can see that I added `now()` to specify the file name as the target workbook.

Would this be even possible? I find it faster than doing a VBA macro.

Comment: Did either of our answers help solve your problem? If so, then please choose to accept an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I wrote a VBA code for this one. As for my estimation for future running of the file. This might take quite some time but Thanks all for the Ideas! I'm fairly new to this and your efforts are not wasted. Glad to learn more of this because of people like you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the indirect function to garner a reference to the range that Excel recognizes as such instead of recognizing it as a string.

More on that here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

"Since Excel sees "A1:A10" as a text string rather than a range reference..."

Fair warning, however... the indirect function can be VERY slow. In the past, I found it much better to use a custom VBA function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will use `INDIRECT()`. So `INDIRECT(path&"\attendance"&now()&"!G1I13)` and it will create a reference from the calculation string concatenation.